# restore fragment when user left that particular screen in android jetpack navigation component

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, navigation, android-jetpack

Actually i want screen look as it is same when user left last time,

Android Jetpack navigation component, when i come back using

`navController.popBackStack()`

that time automatically RecyclerView maintaining its position but when i go using

`navController.navigate(id)`

on same fragment that time its not maintaining its position and start from 0 index. how to manage this things any idea ?

i try a lot of suggestion from stack-ovwerflow but no luck

Comment: With your `navigate` call you are trying to move back to the previous fragment? Could `navigateUp()` be what you want here?

Comment: suppose i go fragment A -> B, then B -> C, now i go C -> A using bottom navigationView